# Can an objective-c object be used as a prototype of Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ios, prototype, javascriptcore

Let's assume that in iOS:

```
@implementation SomeClass
- (void)sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
}
@end

...

context[@"NativeObject"] = [SomeClass new];
```

Then in Javascript:

```
var test = {};
test.__proto__ = NativeObject;
```

Why is it that when I check:

```
!!NativeObject; //returns true
test.__proto__ === NativeObject; //returns false
test.__proto__ === undefined; //returns true
"sayHello" in test; //returns true
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test).indexOf("sayHello") == -1; //returns true
```

Since the last 2 tests imply there is a prototype, why do the 2nd and 3rd test say there isn't one? Is JavascriptCore broken or am I missing something critical about how it's implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. The answer comes from the `JSExport` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/JavaScriptCore/Reference/JSExport_Ref/index.html):

> In JavaScript, inheritance is supported via a chain of prototype
>   objects. For each Objective-C class you export, JavaScriptCore creates
>   a prototype within the enclosing JavaScript context (a JSContext
>   object). For the NSObject class, the prototype object is the
>   JavaScript context's Object prototype. For all other Objective-C
>   classes, JavaScriptCore creates a prototype object whose internal
>   [Prototype] property points to the prototype property created for the
>   Objective-C class's superclass. As such, the prototype chain for a
>   JavaScript wrapper object reflects the wrapped Objective-C type's
>   inheritance hierarchy.
>
> In addition to the prototype object, JavaScriptCore produces a
>   JavaScript constructor object for each Objective-C class.

I put an [OS X test project on github](https://github.com/drichardson/NativeObjectPrototypes) that demonstrates this which produces the following output:

```
!!NativeObject EQUALS true
test.__proto__ === NativeObject EQUALS true
test.__proto__ === undefined EQUALS false
"sayHello" in test EQUALS true
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test).indexOf("sayHello") == -1 EQUALS true
```

A few observations:

1. `test.__proto__ === NativeObject` always returned `true` whereas you saw it return `false`.
2. `test.__proto__ === undefined` always returned `false` whereas you saw it return `true`.

I also ran a test where I commented out the JSExport protocol, that that had the effect of removing SomeClass from the prototype chain, but the prototype chain still existed, which based on the documentation I assume was NSObject's prototype:

```
!!NativeObject EQUALS true
test.__proto__ === NativeObject EQUALS true
test.__proto__ === undefined EQUALS false
"sayHello" in test EQUALS false
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test).indexOf("sayHello") == -1 EQUALS true
```

Comment: I can go with that. I guess I'll just have to assume that there's something strange going on in the toolkit I was working with.